# Get errors from my PHP code

Tags: php, error-handling

I would just like to know how I can get the actual error message that my PHP code returns. At the moment, all that happens when I have an error is that my browser gives me the message, "Server Error".

Thanks
Tom.

Comment: Most likely the error is being caught by a handler. Are you using a special framework? Could you post your code?

Comment: I tried all others. None of what I found worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you probably have everything disabled in php.ini. You can, at runtime, modify those values with the following statements:

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
ini_set("display_startup_errors", "On");
```